# How to work with static variables in clases with the Android NDK?

Tags: c++11, android-ndk, static-variables

I'm just trying to compile with NDK a simple class (that works with GCC compilation):

ShaderProgramManager.h:

```
namespace Graphics {

class ShaderProgramManager {
public:
    ShaderProgramManager();
    virtual ~ShaderProgramManager();
    static Graphics::ZGLProgram* ColoredVertexProgram;
};

} /* namespace Graphics */
```

ShaderProgramManager.cpp:

```
#include "ShaderProgramManager.h"

namespace Graphics {

ShaderProgramManager::ShaderProgramManager() {
    ShaderProgramManager::ColoredVertexProgram=new ZGLProgram();
}
```

The error is:

```
undefined reference to 'Graphics::ShaderProgramManager::ColoredVertexProgram'
```

If I declare the variable non-static there is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. To properly define static variables they must be redeclared in compilation units and outside methods.

The correct ShaderProgramManager.cpp in this case:

```
#include "ShaderProgramManager.h"

namespace Graphics {

Graphics::ZGLProgram* ShaderProgramManager::ColoredVertexProgram;

ShaderProgramManager::ShaderProgramManager() {
    ColoredVertexProgram=new ZGLProgram();
}
```